# Nhibernate mapping of System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Question: I get an exception serializing this class to a nHibernate xml file ({"Could not determine type for: System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Settings)"}).

How to map System.Drawing.Image to nHibernate ?
And what MS-SQL dbtype is to be used?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace nhDBapi.Tables
{

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Class(Name = "nhDBapi.Tables.clsSettings, nhDBapi", Table = "lsSettings")]
    public class clsSettings
    {

        [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Id(Name = "Settings", Column = "Settings", TypeType = typeof(System.Drawing.Image))]
        public System.Drawing.Image Settings;

    } // End partial class lsSettings


} // End Namespace nhDBapi.Tables
```

Comment: it's not cool to delete questions that already have answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913875/nhibernate-detachedquery-equivalent-for-hql you waste people's time...

Comment: I merely deleted a question that had no useful answer.It doesn't work with a non var datatype, that's all there is to it. And I don't intend to use var. I want compile-time type-checking.

Comment: `var` is compile-time checked. It's not a datatype. It's just a keyword. Mauricio's answer seems good to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend mapping directly to System.Drawing.Image. Not only is it disposable (NHibernate would have to dispose it and I'm not sure it can), but also if you fetch a collection of `clsSettings` you'll be creating lots of Image instances, thus wasting CPU and memory if you don't use all of them.

Instead, map to a `byte[]` with sql type varbinary and *you* handle converting from and to Image as necessary. [Example](http://kozmic.pl/2009/05/19/storing-long-text-and-binary-blobs-with-nhibernate/).

Also worth checking out is this project about [large object storage support for NHibernate](http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2009/03/large-object-storage-for-nhibernate-and-ddd-part-1-blobs-clobs-and-xlobs/), seems to be more efficient than mapping to a `byte[]` and it's also an excellent article about all options.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use an IUserType.
[See this example including mappings](http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/nhibernate/usertype.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're advocating storing an image in the database, this is rarely a good idea because of the huge overhead. Do you have a good reason for doing this? Is this a web app or a client desktop app?

Far better solution is to store the image in the file system and use the database to store meta-data about the image, such as filename, caption etc.

But as Mauricio Scheffer says, if you must do this then you're probably better off using a byte[] array, or maybe use some custom type that encapsulates a byte[] array and gives you helper methods such as `public Image GetBitmapImage();`

Comment: I too usually recommend storing images in the filesystem, but everything has its pros and cons, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay . And SQL Server 2008 has the filestream type which AFAIK is a big improvement about this.